# How to show multi-avatar in iOS communication notification?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

Like the image I attached, I want to show 2 avatars in the notification. But I was only able to show just 1 avatar.

```swift
intent = INSendMessageIntent(
    recipients: [senderPerson, testPerson, mePerson],
    outgoingMessageType: .outgoingMessageText,
    content: bodyForNoti,
    speakableGroupName: INSpeakableString(spokenPhrase: roomTitle),
    conversationIdentifier: roomId,
    serviceName: nil,
    sender: senderPerson,
    attachments: nil
)
intent.setImage(avatar, forParameterNamed: \.speakableGroupName)

let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
interaction.direction = .incoming
interaction.donate(completion: nil)
```